# Is it possible to create a tiebraker when the rank function returns two records with 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I use the following script to rank the reservations by number of times the Category displays:

```
with 
Stays as (
select
    [Site],
    Reservation,
    Arrival,
    Departure,
    Category,
    count(*) as [Count],
    rank() over (
        partition by [Site], Reservation
        order by count(*) desc
        ) RankNum
from #Reservations
group by
    [Site],
    Reservation,
    Arrival,
    Departure,
    Category
)

select *
from Stays
where RankNum = 1
```

I run into an issue where I have multiple records = 1, thus I need a tiebreaker. If the category = "Owner", the tiebreaker goes to Owner, otherwise, it's the oldest record (I didn't include the create date above). Ultimately, I need to get to two unique stays with the appropriate category. Is this an operation I can perform via SQL?

Comment: How about adding a `case` expression that either returns _the beginning of time_ if `'Owner'` or the record date? Order by that (descending) or use it in `Row_Number()` and pick row `1`.

Comment: The `order by` is not limited to a single value. You could potentially use `rank over(... order by count(*) desc, Arrival, Departure, Category)`, which would yield a distinct, repeatable, well-defined ranking. For your specific case, you could insert `case when Category = 'Owner' then 1 else 2 end` and then `Created` to the order immediately after the count..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HABO and @TN mentioned yes, you can perform the required operations in SQL to handle the tiebreaker condition based on the category and the oldest record.

```
CREATE TABLE #Reservations (
  [Site] INT,
  Reservation varchar(50),
  Arrival date,
  Departure date,
  Category varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Reservations ([Site], Reservation, Arrival, Departure, Category)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Reservation 1', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', 'Owner'),
  ('1', 'Reservation 1', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', 'Owner'),
  ('1', 'Reservation 2', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-15', 'Guest'),
  ('1', 'Reservation 3', '2023-01-20', '2023-01-25', 'Guest'),
  ('1', 'Reservation 4', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-05', 'Guest'),
  ('1', 'Reservation 4', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-05', 'Owner'),
  ('1', 'Reservation 5', '2023-02-10', '2023-02-15', 'Owner');

WITH Stays AS (
  SELECT
    [Site],
    Reservation,
    Arrival,
    Departure,
    Category,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY [Site], Reservation
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, CASE WHEN Category = 'Owner' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Arrival ASC
    ) AS RowNum,
    CASE WHEN Category = 'Owner' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Tiebreaker
  FROM #Reservations
  GROUP BY
    [Site],
    Reservation,
    Arrival,
    Departure,
    Category
)
SELECT *
FROM Stays
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

| Site | Reservation | Arrival | Departure | Category | RowNum | Tiebreaker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Reservation 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 | Owner | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Reservation 2 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-15 | Guest | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Reservation 3 | 2023-01-20 | 2023-01-25 | Guest | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Reservation 4 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-05 | Owner | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Reservation 5 | 2023-02-10 | 2023-02-15 | Owner | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/79nWK0A7)

The `CASE WHEN Category = 'Owner' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC` will order by the category, giving priority to the "Owner" category when it occurs.
Adding the `Arrival ASC` will give the priority to the oldest record.

This way, if there are multiple records with the same count, the tiebreaker will first prioritize the "Owner" category, and if not applicable, it will choose the oldest record based on the arrival date.

I assume a common issue that can affect performance in this scenario is the lack of appropriate indexes.
For example, if your `#Reservations` table contains a large number of records and the query involves filtering or joining on columns like `[Site]`, `Reservation`, or `Category`, it's important to have indexes on these columns. Without indexes, the database engine would need to scan the entire table to find the relevant rows, leading to slower performance.

Just to follow the best practices, if the dataset continues to grow over time, it's important to regularly update the table statistics.